# Define form as service in Symfony 3

Tags: php, forms, service, symfony

I need to define my form as a service so I could inject some dependencies into it (for example Entity Manager). I followed tutorial on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service , but the result is

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyFirm\Form\ItemAmountType::__construct() must be an instance of MyFirm\Form\EntityManager, none given, called in /var/www/html/ordering-system/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 85 and defined

I have a form registred as a service:

```
services:
    my_firm.form.item_amount:
        class: MyFirm\Form\ItemAmountType
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@price_list_manager" ]
```

Then I create the form in controller:

```
$itemAmount = new ItemAmount();
$form = $this->createForm( ItemAmountType::class, $itemAmount );
```

Construct of the form:

```
class ItemAmountType extends AbstractType {

    private $em;
    private $priceListManage;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, PriceListManager $priceListManager) {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->priceListManage = $priceListManager;
    }
    //...
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: You left out the form tag in your service: tags: [{ name: form.type }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left out the form tag in

```
service:
    tags: [{ name: form.type }]
```